# How to pass a boolean parameter from Route Guards in Angular

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-router-guards, angular-routerlink, canactivate

I need to guard the routerLinks based on some boolean configurations coming from a server. Currently i have written `canActivate` route guard. `ActivateRoutes` file

```
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<any> {
        const visibility = route.data.name;
        return await this.service.activateRouterLinks(visibility);
}
```

This my app.module.ts file

```
{
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: 'src/app/home/home.module#HomeModule',
        data: {
            title: 'Home', name: Names.HOME
        },
        canActivate: [ActivateRoutes]
    },
```

But actually what i want is i want to pass a boolean value to data like this instead of name.

```
 data: {
                    title: 'Home', state: homePageActive
                },
```

that coming from my service class (the route guard). Currently I am using a map and every time page loads it will search all the map to find the name. Therefore I want to set for a boolean value at once.

This is my service class code.

```
 linkNames = new Map<string, []>();
 homePageActive = false;
 getConfigurations() {
        this.getUIConfigurations().subscribe(
            configs => {
                for (const value of configs.names) {
                    this.linkNames.set(value.name, value.secondary_tabs);
                }
             mapNames();
            });
    }

mapNames() {
        if (this.linkNames.has(Names.HOME)) {
           homePageActive = true;
        }
}

asyn cactivateRouterLinks(visibility) {
        await this.waitSecond();
        if (this.linkNames.has(visibility)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/page_not_found');
            return false;
        }
    }

waitSecond() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('return aftersecond!');
            }, 160);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass data from `RouteGuard` to a component, but `RouteGuards` are only used to guard whether the user has access to a component.

Instead, use a [Resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#resolve-guard).

---

### What's a resolver?

A resolver allows you to perform certain actions before a component loads as well as pass data to that component. It's often used to pre-fetch data so it's ready as soon as the component loads.

It also allows you to handle errors before routing to the component, there's no point rendering a component that errors, therefore it can also be used to improve performance.

---

### Example:

Here's a simple setup of how it works:

First, create a Resolver service (very similar to a guard)

```js
@Injectable()
export class YourResolver implements Resolve<ReturnedData> {

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<ReturnedData> {
        return this.myService.getData();
    }
}
```

Then in your Router:

```js
  {
            path: '', 
            component: YourComponent,
            resolve: {
                myData: YourResolver
            }, 
 },
```

You can then access it from your component like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.data
    .subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data.myData)
    });
}
```

Comment: `data: {  title: 'Home', name: Names.HOME }`, instead of this i want to use  `resolve: { data: YourResolver},`  resolver

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: In app.module.ts file i have like this  `data: { title: 'Home', name: Names.HOME},` in routing .Without adding that one i want to add  ` resolve: { data: YourResolver},`   this piece of code.

Comment: Ok so what's the specific problem you are facing?

Comment: Actually i am asking is that the thing i want to do?

Comment: `this.myService.getData()`  what i want to implement in this method?

Comment: Yes, that's the logic you want to implement before the router gets resolved